# How to turn on emacs auto-fill-mode only for code comments?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, autofill

I have tried

```
(set (make-local-variable 'comment-auto-fill-only-comments) t)
```

and also

```
(auto-fill-mode 0)
```

**Though amazingly, neither of those work after emacs is restarted.**

I am using [eschulte's emacs starter kit](https://github.com/eschulte/emacs-starter-kit)

Toggling it works fine with M-x auto-fill-mode.

---

## **UPDATE**

Using a combination of (thanks Rémi):

```
(auto-fill-mode 1)
(setq comment-auto-fill-only-comments t)
```

It works perfectly within programming files, where there are comments. However, in text mode, it auto-fills everywhere.

How can I turn off auto-fill-mode completely when inside text documents?

Comment: Emacs has detailed online documentation. It might be helpful to use `describe-function`, `describe-variable` to find out how you could use a function, a variable.

Comment: try `describe-variable`, it may show you that `comment-auto-fill-only-comments` is not what you think it is.  If that's the case, then possibly there's a hook running after you set the value, that stomps on your value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want Emacs to auto-fill comments you must not make comment-auto-fill-only-comments a local variable:

```
(setq comment-auto-fill-only-comments t)
```

If you want it only in some mode but not all you have to add it to the correct hook:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 
          (lambda () ((set (make-local-variable 'comment-auto-fill-only-comments) t)))
```

**UPDATE answer**

To remove auto-fill from text mode, you have to use hook:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 
          (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))
```

Note that this will change also the auto-fill state in mode deriving off text-mode (latex-mode is one examples, there are a lot of other such mode)

Comment: Thank you - an update to this has been posted on my question - it is partially solved but some issues remain.